# How to pass "this" as well as v-model from input to handler

Tags: javascript, vue.js, this, v-model

How do I pass the `this` object (referring to the input element vs. whole component) to a handler function in Vue?

```
<input
  type="number"
  min="0"
  max="8000000"
  step="100000"
  v-model="minPriceInput"
  @change="setPriceRange(minPriceInput, maxPriceInput)"
/>
```

methods:

```
setPriceRange(min, max) {
  this.blur(); // or whatever else I might do with the input
  state.commit("setPriceRange", [min, max]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the event with the parameters as follows `setPriceRange($event, minPriceInput, maxPriceInput);` and use it through `event.target`.
Another thing you can do is giving it an id and calling it normally using `document.getElementById("minPrice")`...